# Почему не выполняется callback?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, response) => {
handleExtAction(request, sender, response);
console.log(request);
console.log(sender);
console.log(response);
});

function handleExtAction(request, sender, response) {
switch (request.action) {
    case 'getNotifyAccess':
        chrome.storage.sync.get(['config'], function(result) {
            result = result.config;

            if (result.api_token === undefined || result.api_token === '') return;

            $.get(url + result.api_token + '/access', (data, textStatus, xhr) => {
                console.log(xhr.status);
            }).fail(() => {
                response({
                    success: false,
                    error: 'server not available',
                });
            });
        });
        break;
}
}
```

Callback response возвращает undefined.

Если его вызвать из

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, response) => {
response({success: true, error: ''});
```

то он сработает.

Также из функции handleExtAction тоже работает.

```
function handleExtAction(request, sender, response) {
response({success: true, error: ''});
```

Почему он возвращает undefined при вызове из jquery fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) вам необходимо вернуть `true` в теле обработчика сообщения в случае если вы планируете работать асинхронно.

Решение:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, response) => {
  handleExtAction(request, sender, response);
  console.log(request);
  console.log(sender);
  console.log(response);
  return true; // <---
});

...
```